# PHP's addcslashes ignoring some chars

Tags: php, string, function

I would like to know why the function addcslashes() is ignoring certain characters.
As you will notice in the output at the bottom, ["`","$","""] are being ignored.

This is my example:

```
<?php
$ADPasswdRaw = $_GET["element_3"]; #data from a web form
$ADPasswd = addcslashes($ADPasswdRaw, "~`!@#$%^&*()_+=-][}{\\|:;\"',./<>?");

echo $ADPasswd;
?>
```

**Output**

```
\~\`\!\@\\\#$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\-\=\;\:"\'\<\>\?\,\.\/
```

Thanks

Comment: No problem showed here: https://3v4l.org/S175J Maybe it's the type of your input

Comment: And why are you not using `password_hash()`?

Comment: I'm using it to do an imapsync @RyanVincent

Comment: Sorry @Xorifelse , I'm not aware of password_hash(); I'm new clearly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This must be a problem with my input.

This is unclear and old at this point.